# Reference book for Calculus Conceptual problems

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

[self-study]

I have an exam of Mathematics conducted by IIT. I am comfortable in mathematical problems involving limits or integration. I am not comfortable with some special kinds of problems where we are provided with some information related to differentiability and continuity and after analysing those information, we have to come up with appropriate answers. To give you example, the following type of problems,I am talking about. [image]

[image]

The above problems are just for example. I don't want any help regarding problems. I just want to know whether there is any book which includes these kinds of problems to practice where we have to analyse the given informations and choose appropriate answers.

Comment: K.D.Joshi calculus is also suitable for IIT JEE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is based on sequences and second is about applications of limit/continuity/differentiability. For such problems I would suggest you

$1$. Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle &  Sherbert

$2$. Understanding Analysis by Stephen A. Abott

$3$. Mathematical Analysis by Apostol

You can find all topics in these books which you are looking for.

If you prefer Indian writers as you are going to write an exam conducted by IIT's , these books might be helpul.

$1$. Real Analysis by Sadhan Kumar Mapa (It is full of  some good problems.)

$2$. Mathematical Analysis by Shantinarayan , S.Chand publication .

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This book is very introductory to analysis. *'How to think about analysis'*, Lara Alcock, Oxford University Press.